# image transparent gradient with canvas and js, using canvasimagegradient

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas, gradient

im tryin to use this simple function:
http://code.google.com/p/canvasimagegradient/
i have to create a linear transparent gradient with canvas and js (my image must be dynamic) but my code it's not working..
can you tell me where im wrong?

```
var ctx = $('#thecanvas')[0].getContext("2d");
var theImage= $('#theimage');

var linearGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, theImage.height);
linearGradient.addColorStop(0, "transparent");
linearGradient.addColorStop(1, "#000");

ctx.drawImageGradient(theImage, 12, 65, linearGradient);
```

the debugger just says me:
the console says me:

```
NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9: The implementation did not support
```

just under this row:

```
var linearGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, theImage.height);
```

thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because you are getting the image as a jQuery object, where height is a function, not a property?  so you should have `theImage.height()`, not `theImage.height` ?

Comment: Nice catch. Or, alternatively, `theImage[0].height`.

Comment: thanks a lot! and directly from the function's creator: "ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);" you must fill the canvas before apllying the gradient